# Call method implemented in derived classes by iterating the base class vector

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a C++ design problem regarding the base class and the derived class.
Here is the code looks like:

```
class BaseClass:
{
  public:
     BaseClass();
     virtual ~BaseClass();
     //...Some basic functions for the derived Classes
     void write_data(void* data);
};

class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
{
  public:
     DerivedClass1(){}
     ~DerivedClass1() override{}
     void method(Type1 data);
}

class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass
{
  public:
     DerivedClass2(){}
     ~DerivedClass2() override{}
     void method(Type2 data);
}
// There are hundreds of auto-created derived classes
.....
```

The class that instantiates the derived classes uses a vector to store the instantiated derived classes:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>> m_factory_vector;
```

The function that stores the classes is:

```
template<typname Type>
void fun(Type& data)
{
   std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> base= std::make_unique<Type>(*file_);
   base.get()->method(data);
   m_factory_vector.push_back(base);
}
```

The reason that using the template is due to the number of functions call the `fun` is unknown.

Now I would like to iterate through the vector and call the method in the derived classes again. Because the methods write a different type of data into the HDF5 file by collecting the data in a buffer(size 100, but the total size is unknown), but there is some data remaining in the collected batch that I would like to flush when the program is ended. Here is the problem I am having, I wish I can do it like:

```
for(hsize_t i=0;i<m_factory_vector.size();i++)
{
   m_factory_vector[i]->method({});
}
```

But I know the problem is the method is not in the BaseClass but in the derived classes. But the method in derived classes has different types of input parameters that I may not able to declare `virtual void method()` in BaseClass. However, I still want to have something like this so that I can call flush those data into the database without losing the data.

Comment: While inconvenient, a virtual method called `flush` seems like the most straightforward approach...

Answer (score 0):

Without reworking your design, you might use `dynamic_cast`:

```
for (hsize_t i=0;i<m_factory_vector.size();i++)
{
   if (auto* p = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass1>(m_factory_vector[i]->get()))
       p->method({});
   else if (auto* p = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass2>(m_factory_vector[i]->get()))
       p->method({});
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I have put this into consideration. But there are hundreds of derived classes. And which class has been used is also unknown. That is why I used a template to instantiate the classes.

Comment: if you don't know the classes, and the common interface isn't enough, how do you want to use them?

Comment: @JianyuanMa Then put the method in the base class. Make it virtual.

Comment: @Jarod42 As a user knows classes call the template function fun. But the problem is the usage of the baseclass vector is outside of the place that the user called the template function. And I want to use this vector in a general way, then the user does not need to consider add another dynamic_cast. Plus there might be a lot of functions called the template function, but for the vector itself does not know which derived class has been instantiated.

Comment: If you want to use vector in a generic way, only use interface, so you probably have to enrich it (as proposed `virtual void flush() /*= 0*/;` method).